# Найти количество слов в которой заданная буква встречается более 1-го раза. C++

Tags: c++, строки

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту задачу, все никак не получается, что то делаю не правильно, но не знаю что, результат всегда выбивает 0. 
Полное задание: "В заданной строке найти количество слов, в которых заданная буква встречается более 1 раза."

Мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[100] = "robert, error, work, rob, refferi";
    char ch;

    cout << str << endl;

    int counter = 0; 

    char* ptr = strtok(str, " ,.!?:");

    cout << "Enter a letter: "; 
    cin >> ch; 

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (ptr[i] == ' ' && ptr[strlen(ptr) - 1] == ch) {
            counter++;
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    }

    if (ch > 1) {
        cout << "Number of words with a letter " << ch << " equally " << counter << "\n";
    }
}
```

Я искал количество слов, в которых буква "r" встречается более 1 раза, в самой строке есть такие слова, но результат - 0. За помощь буду благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ptr[i] == ' ' && ptr[strlen(ptr) - 1] == ch) {
        counter++;
}
```

Вы считаете слова, где первая буква пробел (а она им быть не может из-за `strtok`, а последняя `ch`.

Напишите что-то с поиском `strchr` или хотя бы простой перебор:

```
int bukv = 0;
for(int i = 0; p[i]; i++)
    if (p[i] == ch)
        if (++bukv == 2) {
            counter++;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, что указали где проблема, только все оказалось намного проще, я изменил условие:

```
if (ptr[strlen(ptr) - 2] == ch) { 
   counter++; }
```

Теперь оно правильно ищет количество